# how to get and store android app startup launching time

Tags: android, time, launch

How to get value of application launching time,
from available solution on android log is printed like this I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.android.demo.MainActivity: +1s751ms
Any solution to store this value in variable to use further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think is possible to store that value somehow outside Android Studio because this things and others involving performance issues are viewable only inside SDK. For further references see this:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time